# C - AND operator between two arrays

Tags: c, arrays, substring

I want to subsample an array based on a true-false vector:

```
array1 - ughIuytLikeretC

array2 - ffftfffttttffft
```

Such that `array1 && array2` yields:

```
array3 - ILikeC
```

What I have done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {

    char source[16] = "ughIuytLikeretC\0";
    bool mask[15] = {
        false, false, false, true, false,
        false, false, true, true, true,
        true, false, false, false, true,
    };
    char *filtered;
    filtered = malloc(16 * sizeof(char));

    int j = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if (mask[i]) {
            filtered[j] = source[i];
            j += 1;
        }
    }
    filtered[j] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", filtered);
    free(filtered);
}
```

My questions are:
Is this an OK way of doing it or is there a sleeker way of achieving this?

Comment: You forgot to initialise `j`.

Comment: Also do not forget to terminate `array3` with a `'\0'` character.

Comment: @Osiris Truth!!! thanks.

Comment: Also note `array1` needs a size of at least 16 to hold `"ughIuytLikeretC"`.

Comment: Is it an OK way of solving the problem? -- Yes.  Is there a way to use bitwise AND to improve the code? -- No, not that I see.  All of your data are arranged in byte-size or larger units, so I don't really see a reason even to consider bitwise operations.

Comment: Is the goal to form a _string_ at `array3` or to print select characters of `array1[]`?

Comment: @chux, to form new string

Comment: For a slightly slicker alternative: `for (i = 0; array1[i]; i++){  array3[j] = array1[i]; j += array2[i];    } array3[j] = 0;`

Comment: Thanks @chux, that was pretty slick, but why does the loop not stop at the first false in array1?

Comment: @jregalad Unclear about "first false in array1".  Did you mean _null chracter_?  Are you asking why `for (i = 0; array1[i]; i++)` iterates about 15 times? (it does stop at the first _null chracter_.)

Comment: $chux, sorry messed the arrays, now I get it, many thanks!!

Comment: @jregalad Note: "messed the arrays" --> next time use more informative object names than `array1, array2, array3`.  Perhaps `source, enable, destination`?

Comment: "ughIuytLikeretC\0" requires 17 characters; you have two nulls at the end - the one the compiler put there and an explicit one.  Safet to leave the `[]` empty and the compiler will supply the correct length for the initialiser.

Comment: Better also to ask if there is a better way rather than being explicit about wanting a solution using bit-wise AND.  I see no scope for using bitwise-AND here. An array if indices `{3,7,8,9,10,14}` would seem to make more sense.

Comment: Also, not sure what your intention was though, you don't need to put the \0 in the "ughIuytLikeretC" string as C literal strings have an implicit \0 at the end.

Comment: For working code, it is always a much better idea to post on the Code Review Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, this is an OK way of doing this.

From an algorithmic perspective, this is an acceptable solution as you are required to build an additional array, which you are doing.

I'm ignoring the small caveats as pointed out in the comments.

Note: I would create a function something like `and_arrays(const char a[], const char b[], char result[]);` where you need to pass an allocated array for the result parameter.